# Which of the following identities are true? Justify your answer - n! = O(4^n)..

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, computer-science

**Which of the following identities are true? Justify your answer**

a)**$n! = O(4^n)$**

b)**$4^n = O(n!)$**

If I let $n = 0$ then $(0)! = O(4^0) \implies 1 = O(1)$ so this is true I think?

$4^n = O(n!)$

In that case, wouldn't this be true as well?

Comment: I think you don't really understand the big-O notation at all...

Comment: Yea, I don't. Enlighten me

Comment: Can you write out the definition of big $O$ notation? (As you understand it)

Comment: This site is to answer questions and help. If you've done a fair share of reading, then I will gladly help you. If you haven't read the definition, I won't do your share of googling.

Comment: Big O notation is just the run-time of the Algorithm based on how big the inputs get.. At least that was my understanding from it

Comment: Why is this tagged discrete mathematics?

Comment: The applicable definition is that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ if and only if there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $0 \leq f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$. If you find such constants $c$ and $n_0$ then you have shown that the identity is true.

Comment: Worded in a more layman's sort of way, if $n=10^{10^{100}}$ or some other absurdly large number, which is bigger?  $n!$ or $4^n$?  Hint: in $n!$ a large portion of the $n$ numbers in the product will be bigger than $16$.

Comment: I like @JMoravitz's comment. That's a good way to think about it conceptually. My comment was more of how you could verify mathematically as the justification that your question requires.

Comment: yea so letting $n = 10$ .. $10! = 3628800 > 4^{10} = 1048576$

Comment: So you found $4^{10}<10!$.  Does it follow that $4^{11}<11!$?  If it is true that $4^k<k!$ does it follow that $4^{k+1}<(k+1)!$?  Can you use this then with the definition that @samalamma gave? (maybe using $c=1$ and $n_0=10$?)

Comment: Oh I think I get it. so letting $c = 1$, & letting $n = k + 1$ where $k = 10$ means that $ 0 \le f(10) \le (1) * g(10)$ which means that $f(x) = O(g(x))$

Comment: My comment with the $k$'s was to try to lead you to an induction proof that $4^n<n!$ for all $n\geq 10$.  Once you know that $4^n<n!$ for all $n\geq 10$ you can say $0\leq 4^n\leq (1)\cdot n!$ for all $n\geq 10$.  Which does this show?  $n!=O(4^n)$ or $4^n=O(n!)$?  Note, what about the reverse inequality?  A way of reading "$f(n)=O(g(n))$" is "$f(n)$ *is bounded by some multiple of* $g(n)$."  (the notion of being dominated is a bit stronger.  read more on the wiki page for that)

Comment: So I found that $n! \notin O(4^n)$ by letting $n = 10$ and letting $c = 1$. Then I found that $4^n \in O(4^n)$ is that the correct way to say it? Basically I found that the second identity is true.

Comment: Also is it correct to say that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ **iff** $\exists$ positive constants $C$ and $n_0$ $|0 \le f(n) \le c * g(n),$ $\forall$ $n \ge n_0|$

Answer (score -1):

You need to go back to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big O. Let $f$, $g$ be functions of $x$. Then $f = O(g)$ if and only if there exists some number $M$ such that $\left|f\right| \le M\left|g\right|$. In other words, if you can find a constant $M$ such that$$\left|f\right| \le M \times \text{some other function},$$then $f$ is $O(g)$.

Here is an example. Let $f = 6x^4 - x^2 + 5$. Then$$\left|6x^4 - x^2 + 5\right| \le \left|6x^4 + x^2 + 5\right| \le \left|6x^4 + x^4 + 5x^4\right| = 12\left|x^4\right|.$$That is why we would say $f = O(x^4)$, since there exists a constant, namely $12$, that fits our definition of big O. In your case, you need to figure out which equation is larger, or rather, which graph produces an upper bound for the other – to that extent, [this](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/function/growth_files/summary.gif) graph should help. Anyways, the reason big O is useful is because it provides a function $f$ with an upper bound (worst case) of another function. In our example above, the worst case was $x^4$, hence why $f$ was big O of $x^4$.